# How to make FB.Event.subscribe for edge.create trigger when user done with comment?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response){location.href = 'test.php'});
```

This triggers very shortly after the "Like" button is pressed (I'm assuming as soon as the response from FB is received).

The problem is that clicking the FB button fires the event before the user has a chance to fill out the comment box.  Because my code sends the user to another page they loose the opportunity to enter a comment.

Is there a way to delay the edge.create event until the user is done with the entire process?

If not, what would be the best approach to solve this issue.  I need to enter the previously typed-in email address into a database and let the user know that they got a reward for liking the page.

I tried to subscribe to the comment notification but it didn't work.  Maybe this doesn't work with the "Like" button:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response){...});
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this: instead of immediately changing locations, put a button that will let the user continue. Hide the button until you get the event, then show it. That way they like the page, then the button shows for them to click but before they click they can add a comment.